# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {xxxxxxxxx} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered

Tags: c#, .net-core, registry

I have .Net Core project which rely on some third party libraries. I have used portability analyzer tool analyze the project, which is 100 at .Net Core + Playform Extensions.

The project Platform target is "Any CPU".

But after executing the command dotnet myapp.dll, I still got following error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

The dll is registered under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\

Why I am getting this error even it's already registered? Thanks!

Comment: what sort of project is this? Are you on 64 bit machine?

Comment: Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit process (if you are running on a 64-bit machine, if the exe is built "ANY CPU" (and not "prefer 32-bit"), then it's probably 64-bit. That registration is for a 32-bit component.

Comment: @JohnB  The Platform target is "Any CPU".